# How to display a column data which appear more than 3 times in the sql database without duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this table called memberreport where member can send multiple reports. However, I'm attempting to do a check on those members whom have submitted more than 3 reports.

Each memberaccount has a unique attribute which is memberID. All of the member report require a member account ( which contain a memberID ) in order to report.

As you can see from my SQL codes below

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select distinct memberID from MemberReport where memberID >= 3", con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ddlNRIC.DataSource = ds;
            ddlNRIC.DataTextField = "memberID";
            ddlNRIC.DataValueField = "memberID";
            ddlNRIC.DataBind();
            con.Close();
```

I'm trying to display out the memberID whom have submitted more than 3 reports. However i receive this error from Visual Studio

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Q12345T' to data type int.
```

The number&letter 'Q12345T' is a memberID. I have the attribute as varchar. But i inserted this line of code which is

```
memberID >= 3
```

Should be able display out memberID whom have submitted more than 3 report which didnt work. I'm trying to display out the memberID whom have submitted more than 3 report in the dropdownlist. I have added a distinct which should be able to prevent duplicated memberID.

Comment: Your line of code is comparing a varchar field against the integer 3. You want to do something like: Select distinct memberID from MemberReport GROUP BY memberID HAVING COUNT(*) > 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` checks the value of the column, not the number of times this column appears int the table. For such task you need `having` clause:

```
select memberID from MemberReport
group by memberID
having (count(memberID) >= 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

> > Select distinct memberID from MemberReport where memberID >= 3

where your member id is a varchar(xx) in sql server is **wrong**

Use `group by` clause on memberID and your condition should be on count>=3 not on memberID.

```
select memberID from MemberReport
group by memberID
having (count(memberID) >= 3)
```